# Python tkinter grid layout problems

Tags: python, layout, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a very simple UI using Tkinter and python, but I'm having trouble sizing GUI elements and using the grid format to place them correctly. Here's a first-order approximation of what I'm trying to have:

[image]

Here's the code I have so far. I keep getting close, but I don't think I really understand what I'm doing. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#User interface
root = Tk()
window_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
window_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry    ("%dx%d"%(window_width,window_height))

menu_bar = Menu(root)
menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label="Open", command = open_file)
menu.add_command(label="Save", command = save)
menu.add_separator()
menu.add_command(label="Quit", command = exit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=menu)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)

#textbox is the window in which the code is written
textbox = Text(root, width=50, height = window_height/20+4)

#canvas is where the car will go
canvas_frame= Frame(root, width = window_width/1.5, height = window_height-200)
canvas_frame.configure(borderwidth=1.5,background='black')
canvas = Canvas(canvas_frame, width = window_width/1.5, height = window_height-200)

#console to print to
console = Text(root, width = int(window_width/1.5), height = 10)

run_button = Button(root, text = "Run", command = lambda:generate_program(textbox.get(1.0,END)))

clear_button = Button(root, text = "Clear text", command = clear)

#add them to frame
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=20, columnspan=10)
run_button.grid(row=21,column=0)
clear_button.grid(row=21,column=1)
canvas_frame.grid(row=0,rowspan=10,column=21,columnspan=25)
canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=1, column=21, columnspan=25)
console.grid(row = 1, rowspan=1, column = 21, columnspan=25)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is layout can be much easier with the pack geometry manager. One of the problems is that you are trying to make the width and the height of each widget fit in its place with `rowspan` and `columspan` options. Also, since `canvas`is inside a frame, you have to think that it is like inside a new window, so a simple call to `canvas.grid()` would be enough.

However, with `pack()` you just have to put `textbox`, `run_button` and `clear_button` inside a new frame:

```
left_frame = Frame(root)
textbox = Text(left_frame, ...)
run_button = Button(left_frame, ...)
clear_button = Button(left_frame, ...)

canvas_frame= Frame(root, ...)
canvas_frame.configure(borderwidth=1.5,background='black')
canvas = Canvas(canvas_frame, ...)
console = Text(root, ...)

left_frame.pack(side=LEFT)
textbox.pack()
run_button.pack(side=LEFT)
clear_button.pack()
canvas_frame.pack()
canvas.pack()
console.pack()
```

Comment: Agreed -- there is very obvious a left side and a right side. I would start with pack for that. Then, on each of those sides there is clearly a top and a bottom section. The nice thing about grid for the top/bottom pieces is that you can assign weights to possibly get a more effective resize behavior. Plus, having a left side and a right side makes it easier to add a paned window in the future.